# why I get ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) in dokku

Tags: python, dokku

I need help.
I'm trying to deploy my Python/Flask app to Dokku server but I get an error and I don't have any idea of how to fix it.
this is the git remote:

```
dokku   dokku@apps.danieldiaz.me:portfolio (fetch)
dokku   dokku@apps.danieldiaz.me:portfolio (push)
```

the app is created on the server, but when I make a:

```
git push dokku
```

or:

```
git push dokku master
```

I get this error:

```
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 292 bytes | 292.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building portfolio from herokuish
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
-----> Unable to select a buildpack
remote: 2021/01/28 22:49:58 exit status 1
remote: 2021/01/28 23:49:58 exit status 1
To apps.danieldiaz.me:portfolio
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@apps.danieldiaz.me:portfolio'
```

The domain `apps.danieldiaz.me` works, I can connect via ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python dependencies could not be detected so Dokku was unable to select the python buildpack. You'll need to have a `requirements.txt` denoting your dependencies in the root of your repo to fix that.

Comment: Thank you so mucho for your help, I'm not native english speaker, I'm learning english, I have the dependecies file, but with wrong name, I named requeriments.txt instead requirements.txt.
once again, thank you so much for your help, I corrected the name and the build worked.
I really feel the need to give you a beer